# How to refresh the one browser window from another?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am creating an application in which

There is datalist for items which contains collapsible panels with edit and delete button in the header panel.

On click of edit button I opened a new browser window for edit details using window.open(); javascript, which contains item details of the respective item and save button.

So I need functionality like when user clicks on save button on edit window, edit window should get closed and the parent page which has datalist should get refreshed. Note: Please consider I have URL of parent page.

For Closing the window I have tried following code:

```
string closeScript = "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>window.close();</script>";

            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(CmsManagementPage),
                                                   "cancelScript",
                                                   closeScript);
```

But the edit window is not closed, and is there any solution for refreshing the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following function in javascript and call on edit button:

```
function editClose(url) {
    window.opener.location=url;
    window.close();
}
```